# How to make li active when the code of the list is reusable in other file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am having a list which is reused in other webpage so i included it in one file and require the same in other webpage where required

I want to make them active for example if MY RESUME IS CLICKED THE li of myresume become active instead of dashboard so i implement jquery in the same file
but everytime i click on other link other than dashboard the active class is only present in Dashboard l . Is it due to because every time I am going to other page the active class is present on dashboard or due to jquery code(i have included cdn of jquery)??

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("li").click(function() {
    // remove classes from all
    $("li").removeClass("active");
    // add class to the one we clicked
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="active"><a href="dashboard.php"><i class="ti-dashboard"></i>Dashboard</a></li>
  <li><a href="resume.php"><i class="ti-wallet"></i>My Resume</a></li>
  <li><a href="employer-list.php"><i class="ti-wallet"></i>Browse Jobs</a></li>
  <li><a href="assess.php?q=1"><i class="ti-wallet"></i>Assessment</a></li>
  <li><a href="jobs.php"><i class="ti-hand-point-right"></i>Applied Jobs</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes that is the reason. If you ajax in the page then you can have you active

Comment: When you switch to the next page, all your old changes are reset. So you would need some code that selects the proper `<li>` on page load and not after `click`.

Comment: Can you tell the refrence from where i can do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the active to stay, you COULD use sessionStorage, but why not just ajax the page

https://plungjan.name/SO/ajaxnav/index.html

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#nav a").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // remove classes from all
    $("#nav li").removeClass("active");
    // add class to the one we clicked
    $(this).closest("li").addClass("active");
    $("#content").load(this.href);
  }).eq(0).click();
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="nav">
  <li class="active"><a href="dashboard.php"><i class="ti-dashboard"></i>Dashboard</a></li>
  <li><a href="resume.php"><i class="ti-wallet"></i>My Resume</a></li>
  <li><a href="employer-list.php"><i class="ti-wallet"></i>Browse Jobs</a></li>
  <li><a href="assess.php?q=1"><i class="ti-wallet"></i>Assessment</a></li>
  <li><a href="jobs.php"><i class="ti-hand-point-right"></i>Applied Jobs</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Since i have not worked with ajax so i have choose jquery

Comment: using this code i can't redirect to other page it just only make my li active.  Can you give ajax code for the same so that i can redirect to other page as well as well as the current page li remain active

Comment: It loads the other pages into the content div - you can use pushstate if you want the url to change too. If the code does not work, then I have  typo or something

Comment: You only need this if you want to link to a sub page from elsewhere. I think you might not need this?