# How do I change the colour of the current page link on a navigation menu

Tags: html, css

I seem to not be able to change the colour of the current page I am on to a permanent colour after you get to the page.

The navigation link changes colour because the link is active when clicked but doesn't stay that colour once I get to the page. It returns to the colour of the whole navigation menu.

```css
#navbar-horizontal-2 ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid rgb(201, 173, 146);
  background-color: linen;
}

#navbar-horizontal-2 li {
  float: left;
}

#navbar-horizontal-2 li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

#navbar-horizontal-2 li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: rgb(201, 173, 146);
}

#navbar-horizontal-2 li a:hover:active {
  background-color: rgb(201, 173, 146);
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar-horizontal-2">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="models.html">Models</a></li>
    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: do you have a same nav duplicated on each page?

Comment: Because of you're using links to redirect the page to a new one the color will reset to its default value once you change page.
If you want to change the color you should add a ```style="background-color: <color>``` in every page depending on the page you are showing

Comment: OR ajax the content: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62356641/295783

Comment: I don't have the same nav duplicated on each page.

Comment: is same `nav` included on each page as a partial component
 or does each page has its own separate `nav`?

Comment: I wasn't very clear in my question. I just want to change the colour of the link in the nav bar of the current page I am on so if I click 'home' the home link in the nav bar changes to a different colour i.e. red while the others stay the same i.e blue etc.

Comment: It is completely clear. You cannot unless you use script to either load the pages into a container or grab the link from the url

Comment: I use the same html code on each page for the navbar on each page and the same css styling (all the code is above is duplicated on each page).

Comment: _I use the same html code on each page for the navbar_ that's all i wanted to know

Comment: Thank you MrPlungjan on explaining the need to use a script to allow the current page tab to have a single colour to show which page I am on.

Answer (score 0):

if you are doing it in pure html, you would need to go to the nav link in each page that corresponds to the page you are in and create a css id for that page and add it to the link For example, in your css:

```
#currPage {
  color:red;
}
```

(this is assuming you are using css page, if not then you need to add this to each page in the head section)

in the home page html

```
<div id="navbar-horizontal-2">
<ul>
  <li><a href="index.html" id="currpage" >Home</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to give each item in your list a class or ID, then you can do this using a script  - you can put it in an external script and include it

Change

```
const page = "/site/about.html".split("/").pop();
```

to

```
const page = location.href.split("/").pop()
```

when tested

```js
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  const page = "/site/about.html".split("/").pop(); // location.href.split("/").pop()
  [...document.querySelectorAll("#navbar-horizontal-2 > ul > li > a")].forEach(link => {
    if (link.href.endsWith(page)) {
      link.classList.add("active")
    }  
  })  
})
```

```css
#navbar-horizontal-2 ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid rgb(201, 173, 146);
  background-color: linen;
}

#navbar-horizontal-2 li {
  float: left;
}

#navbar-horizontal-2 li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

#navbar-horizontal-2 li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: rgb(201, 173, 146);
}

#navbar-horizontal-2 li a:hover:active {
  background-color: rgb(201, 173, 146);
}

#navbar-horizontal-2 .active {
  background-color: rgb(201, 173, 146);
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar-horizontal-2">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="models.html">Models</a></li>
    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**[EDITED]**

Hello,
To be able to do that and keep this simple, you need to change it manually on each page you are on. On your first page (Index.html) you need to add an id to your list items:

```html
<style>
#home {
    background-color:  rgb(201, 173, 146);
}
</style>
<li><a href="index.html" id="home">Home</a></li>
```

or put this in your Index page's css:

```css
#home {
    background-color:  rgb(201, 173, 146);
}
```

Do this on every **page** and you'll be good to go !
I hope my answer helped you !

Comment: All that does it change the colour to that the active link colour permanently and if I navigate to another page, the previous page link colour remains the same. It simply changes the link colour permanently.

Comment: sorry, my bad, I forgot that either you had to put this css code in a <style> tag on each page, either you add a new css file for each page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this jquery i wrote for myself. For demo purposes i changed `about.html` to `js` as this snippet link has `https://stacksnippets.net/js` link.

This checks your current location, splits it to get the last value after `/`, then matches your menu links that contains value after `/` and style it. 
In demo below your link with `js` value is styled.

```js
var loc= window.location.href;
    console.log(loc);

values=loc.split('/');
link=values[values.length-1];
//console.log(link);

    $('#navbar-horizontal-2 ul li').find('a').each(function() {
    //console.log($(this).attr('href').indexOf(link) >= 0);
    if ($(this).attr('href').indexOf(link) >= 0) {
      //console.log($(this));
       $(this).attr("style", "background-color:rgb(201, 173, 146); color:red")
      //console.log("test");
    }
});
```

```css
#navbar-horizontal-2 ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid rgb(201, 173, 146);
  background-color: linen;
}

#navbar-horizontal-2 li {
  float: left;
}

#navbar-horizontal-2 li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

#navbar-horizontal-2 li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: rgb(201, 173, 146);
}

#navbar-horizontal-2 li a:hover:active {
  background-color: rgb(201, 173, 146);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navbar-horizontal-2">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="js">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="models.html">Models</a></li>
    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```