# How to set active class of side nav bar menu?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have side navigation and active class on first **li** of dashboard. When i move to other **li** active class not setting on other **li**. Active class moves to first **li** after page reload. How i can set active class on clicked **li**? I have added script which i tried so far but still not working for me.

```
 <div class="main-menu menu-fixed menu-light menu-accordion menu-shadow" data-scroll-to-active="true">
     <div class="main-menu-content">
         <ul class="navigation navigation-main custom-nav" id="main-menu-navigation" data-menu="menu-navigation">
             <li class="active nav-item"><a href="{{url('/home')}}"><i class="feather icon-home"></i><span class="menu-title" data-i18n="Dashboard">Dashboard</span></a>
             <li class=" nav-item"><a href="{{url('/stats')}}"><i class="feather icon-home"></i><span class="menu-title" data-i18n="Dashboard">Statistics</span></a></li>
             <li class=" nav-item"><a><i class="feather icon-copy"></i><span class="menu-title" data-i18n="Form Elements">Trips Menu</span></a>
                 <ul class="menu-content">
                     <li><a href="{{route('get.users')}}"><i class="feather icon-circle"></i><span class="menu-item" data-i18n="Switch">Users</span></a></li>
                     <li><a href="{{route('get.tours')}}"><i class="feather icon-circle"></i><span class="menu-item" data-i18n="Checkbox">Tours</span></a></li>
                 </ul>
             </li>
        </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if($(".navigation a").attr("href")==window.location.href){
            $(".nav-item").attr("class","active");
        }
        else{
            $(".nav-item").attr("class","");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please make [mre] with actual links in your HTML, so it can be tested.

Comment: Also, you have here two great examples in JS and Jquery on how to change classes based on links and location. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62408576/how-do-i-change-the-colour-of-the-current-page-link-on-a-navigation-menu/62409530#62409530

Comment: What does actual links mean?

Comment: try these two methods: add class and remove class in js

Comment: @NargesGhasemi I tried it but didn't work for me.